# Changing Language Resources at RunTime

Tags: sharepoint, resources

I got a sharepoint-project which has different projects. Each of them has its own language-specific resource-file like resource.en-us.resx, resource.de-de.resx

Now our customer wants to be able to change any text in those resource-files on-the-fly. We all know how dumb this idea is, but have to offer a solution nonetheless.

We could drop the resource-files and store the resources in Lists instead, but that would make a stupid idea even worse.

Is there a smart way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint is ASP.NET application. It is possible to extend resource provider model. You can put all those resources into database and customer can edit text on-the-fly.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx).